# Attempting to test require module returns undefined for anything

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js

I'm new at unit testing but I've tried many methods of getting my script (require module) loaded for use with my mocha test script. No matter what I do I always get undefined when I try to read a property or function or *anything*. Can anyone help point out what may be causing this?

**rmq.js** (script to test)

```
define(['bx_slider/1/bx_slider'], {

    ...

    ansrTotal: 0,

    ...

    init: function(settings) {
        var self = this;

        // do some stuff

        return self;
    }
});
```

**test-bootstrap.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'chai': '/node_modules/chai/chai',
        'bx_slider/1/bx_slider': '/test/lib/bx_slider'
    },
    baseUrl: '/',
    nodeRequire: require
});

mocha.setup({
    ui: 'bdd'
});

require(['test/test'], function() {

    if (window.mochaPhantomJS) {
        mochaPhantomJS.run();
    } else {
        mocha.run();
    }

});
```

**test.js**

```
define(['chai'], function(chai) {

    var expect = chai.expect;
    var rmq = require(['../src/js/rmq']);

    describe('rmq test suite', function() {

        before(function() {
            return rmq.init();
        });

        it('should blah', function() {

            expect(rmq.ansrTotal).to.equal(0);

        });

    });

});
```

If it helps, my directory structure is

```
.
/node_modules
/src
    /js
        rmq.js
/test
    /lib
        bx_slider.js
        require.js
    test-bootstrap.js
    test.js
```

The exact error (for what I have currently written and posted here) in my CLI is

```
Testing: test/test.js
rmq test suite
    "before all" hook
    'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'rmq.init()')
```

Comment: Why are you requiring `rmq` async instead of in your `define` dependencies?

Comment: ["If the module has dependencies, the first argument should be an array of dependency names, and **the second argument should be a definition function**"](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep). `rmq.js` doesn't comply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathletics mentioned in a comment, you could do:

```
define(['chai', '../src/js/rmq'], function(chai, rmq) {
```

If, for some reason, you cannot do that, there's an alternative. (Maybe you simplified your code so much in your question that the reason is no longer apparent.)

```
define(['chai'], function(chai) {

    var expect = chai.expect;

    describe('rmq test suite', function() {
        var rmq;
        before(function (done) {
            require(['../src/js/rmq'], function (_rmq) {
                // Save the module we got to the `rmq` variable.
                rmq = _rmq;
                // Init and call `done` when finished.
                rmq.init().then(done);
            });
        });

        it('should blah', function() {

            expect(rmq.ansrTotal).to.equal(0);

        });

    });

});
```

I have assumed that `rmq.init()` returns a promise since you did `return rmq.init()` in your code, and doing this does not make sense unless `rmq.init()` returns a promise. If that's not the case then you'd have to call `rmq.init()` and then call `done()` after it.

The code you had cannot work because `require(['../src/js/rmq'])` gets the module **asynchronously** so it does not **return** the module. You have to use it like I've shown above.

Comment: I've tried this method before. I just get a generic require error when doing it this way: `Warning: JavaScript error: Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror on line 1765 for http://localhost:3000/test/lib/require.js`.

Comment: I have two methods in my answer. Which one did you try?

Comment: Well, then there's an error `../src/js/rmq` or one of the modules that it requires.